# How do I recall the last sent message in Colloquy?

Tags: mac

In many chat clients you can get the last typed message by hitting the up arrow. It doesn't seem to work in this client. Is that not an available feature or is there some way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [Colloquy's FAQ](http://colloquy.info/project/wiki/FAQs#Isthereawaytoseemysenthistoryaswellastonavigatearoundintheexistingtextwiththearrowkeys):

> **Is there a way to see my sent history as well as to navigate around in the existing text with the arrow keys?**
>   Sent history is controlled by the up/down arrow keys while holding option, switching between panes in a window with command-up/down, and scrolling with home/end/page up/page down; you can use any other key combination to navigate or select text. Change this within the [hidden preferences](http://colloquy.info/project/wiki/Documentation/TipsAndTricks/HiddenPreferences).

So; <kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd> or 
<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd> gives you the last, or next message, respectively.

And per that Hidden Preferences link, it would appear that you can change it to use up/down arrows only by opening `Terminal.app` (either search for `Terminal` via Spotlight, otherwise you can find the app in `Applications > Utilities`), and enter:

`defaults write info.colloquy JVSendHistoryUsesOnlyArrows -bool true`

Restart Colloquy after entering this command if it was already open, and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd> gives you the last message.

<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd> gives you the next message.